# How can I debug my code for the A star algorithm?

Tags: a-star

I have been trying to program different A star algorithms I found online and though they make sense, every implementation I have programmed failed.

This is my Free Pascal code:

```
function getHeuristic(currentXY, targetXY: array of word): word;
begin
    getHeuristic:=abs(currentXY[0]-targetXY[0])+abs(currentXY[1]-targetXY[1]);
end;

function getPath(startingNodeXY, targetNodeXY: array of word; grid: wordArray3; out pathToControlledCharPtr: word; worldObjIndex: word): wordArray2;
var
    openList, closedList: array of array of word; { x/y/g/h/parent x/parent y, total }
    qXYGH: array[0..5] of word; { x/y/g/h/parent x/parent y }
    gridXCnt, gridYCnt: longInt;
    maxF, q, openListCnt, closedListCnt, parentClosedListCnt, getPathCnt, adjSquNewGScore: word;
    openListIndexCnt, closedListIndexCnt, qIndexCnt, successorIndexCnt: byte;
    getMaxF, successorOnClosedList, successorOnOpenList, pathFound: boolean;
begin

    { Add the starting square (or node) to the open list. }
    setLength(openList, 6, length(openList)+1);
    openList[0, 0]:=startingNodeXY[0];
    openList[1, 0]:=startingNodeXY[1];

    setLength(closedList, 6, 0);

    { Repeat the following: }
    { D) Stop when you: }
    { Fail to find the target square, and the open list is empty. In this case, there is no path. }
    pathFound:=false;
    { writeLn('h1'); }
    while length(openList[0])>0 do
    begin

        { A) Look for the lowest F cost square on the open list. We refer to this as the current square. }
        maxF:=0;
        q:=0;
        getMaxF:=true;
        for openListCnt:=0 to length(openList[0])-1 do
        begin
            //writeLn(formatVal('open list xy {} {}, cnt {}, list max index {}', [openList[0, openListCnt], openList[1, openListCnt], openListCnt, length(openList[0])-1]));
            { readLnPromptX; }
            if (getMaxF=true) or (maxF>openList[2, openListCnt]+openList[3, openListCnt]) then
            begin
                getMaxF:=false;
                maxF:=openList[2, openListCnt]+openList[3, openListCnt];
                q:=openListCnt;
            end;
        end;
        for qIndexCnt:=0 to length(qXYGH)-1 do
            qXYGH[qIndexCnt]:=openList[qIndexCnt, q];

        { B). Switch it to the closed list. }
        setLength(closedList, length(closedList), length(closedList[0])+1);
        for closedListIndexCnt:=0 to length(closedList)-1 do
            closedList[closedListIndexCnt, length(closedList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[closedListIndexCnt];

        { Remove current square from open list }
        if q<length(openList[0])-1 then
        begin
            for openListCnt:=q to length(openList[0])-2 do
            begin
                for openListIndexCnt:=0 to length(openList)-1 do
                    openList[openListIndexCnt, openListCnt]:=openList[openListIndexCnt, openListCnt+1];
            end;
        end;
        setLength(openList, length(openList), length(openList[0])-1);

        //writeLn(formatVal('q[x] {}, q[y] {}, startingNodeXY x {}, startingNodeXY y {}, targetNodeXY x {}, targetNodeXY y {}', [qXYGH[0], qXYGH[1], startingNodeXY[0], startingNodeXY[1], targetNodeXY[0], targetNodeXY[1]]));
        { readLnPromptX; }

        { D) Stop when you: }
        { Add the target square to the closed list, in which case the path has been found, or }
        if (qXYGH[0]=targetNodeXY[0]) and (qXYGH[1]=targetNodeXY[1]) then
        begin
            pathFound:=true;
            break;
        end;

        { C) For each of the 8 squares adjacent to this current square … }
        for gridXCnt:=qXYGH[0]-1 to qXYGH[0]+1 do
        begin
            for gridYCnt:=qXYGH[1]-1 to qXYGH[1]+1 do
            begin

                { Adjacent square cannot be the current square }
                if (gridXCnt<>qXYGH[0]) or (gridYCnt<>qXYGH[1]) then
                begin
                    //writeLn(formatVal('gridXCnt {} gridYCnt {} qXYGH[0] {} qXYGH[1] {}', [gridXCnt, gridYCnt, qXYGH[0], qXYGH[1]]));
                    { readLnPromptX; }

                    { Check if successor is on closed list }
                    successorOnClosedList:=false;
                    if length(closedList[0])>0 then
                    begin
                        for closedListCnt:=0 to length(closedList[0])-1 do
                        begin
                            if (closedList[0, closedListCnt]=gridXCnt) and (closedList[1, closedListCnt]=gridYCnt) then
                            begin
                                successorOnClosedList:=true;
                                break;
                            end;
                        end;
                    end;

                    { If it is not walkable or if it is on the closed list, ignore it. Otherwise do the following. }
                    if (gridXCnt>=0) and (gridXCnt<=length(grid[3])-1) and (gridYCnt>=0) and (gridYCnt<=length(grid[3, 0])-1) and (grid[3, gridXCnt, gridYCnt]=0) and (successorOnClosedList=false) then
                    begin

                        { If it isn’t on the open list, add it to the open list. Make the current square the parent of this square. Record the F, G, and H costs of the square. }
                        successorOnOpenList:=false;
                        if length(openList[0])>0 then
                        begin
                            for openListCnt:=0 to length(openList[0])-1 do
                            begin
                                if (openList[0, openListCnt]=gridXCnt) and (openList[1, openListCnt]=gridYCnt) then
                                begin
                                    successorOnOpenList:=true;
                                    break;
                                end;
                            end;
                        end;
                        if successorOnOpenList=false then
                        begin
                            setLength(openList, length(openList), length(openList[0])+1);
                            openList[0, length(openList[0])-1]:=gridXCnt;
                            openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]:=gridYCnt;
                            openList[4, length(openList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[0];
                            openList[5, length(openList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[1];
                            if (openList[0, length(openList[0])-1]=qXYGH[0]) or (openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]=qXYGH[1]) then
                            begin
                                openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]:=openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]+10;
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                                openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]:=openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]+14;
                            end;
                            openList[3, length(openList[0])-1]:=getHeuristic([openList[0, length(openList[0])-1], openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]], [targetNodeXY[0], targetNodeXY[1]]);
                        end
                        else
                        begin

                            { If it is on the open list already, check to see if this path to that square is better, using G cost as the measure (check to see if the G score for the adjacent square is lower if we use the current square to get there (adjacent square
                            new G score = current square G score + 10 (if adjacent squre is vertical or horizontal to current square) or +14 (if it is diagonal); if result is lower than adjacent square current G score then this path is better). A lower G cost means that
                            this is a better path. If so, change the parent of the square to the current square, and recalculate the G and F scores of the square. If you are keeping your open list sorted by F score, you may need to resort the list to account for the
                            change. }
                            adjSquNewGScore:=openList[2, openListCnt];
                            if (openList[0, openListCnt]=qXYGH[0]) or (openList[1, openListCnt]=qXYGH[1]) then
                            begin
                                adjSquNewGScore:=adjSquNewGScore+10;
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                                adjSquNewGScore:=adjSquNewGScore+14;
                            end;
                            if adjSquNewGScore<openList[2, openListCnt] then
                            begin
                                openList[4, openListCnt]:=qXYGH[0];
                                openList[5, openListCnt]:=qXYGH[1];
                                openList[2, openListCnt]:=adjSquNewGScore;
                            end;

                        end;

                    end;

                end;

            end;
        end;

    end;
    { writeLn('h2'); }
    { writeLn(pathFound); }
    { readLnHalt; }

    if pathFound=true then
    begin

        { Save the path. Working backwards from the target square, go from each square to its parent square until you reach the starting square. That is your path. }
        closedListCnt:=length(closedList[0])-1;
        setLength(getPath, 2, 0);

        { While starting node has not been added to path }
        while (length(getPath[0])=0) or (getPath[0, length(getPath[0])-1]<>startingNodeXY[0]) or (getPath[1, length(getPath[0])-1]<>startingNodeXY[1]) do
        begin

            { Add node from closed list to path }
            setLength(getPath, 2, length(getPath[0])+1);
            getPath[0, length(getPath[0])-1]:=closedList[0, closedListCnt];
            getPath[1, length(getPath[0])-1]:=closedList[1, closedListCnt];

            { Find next node on closed list with coord matching parent coord of current closed list node }
            for parentClosedListCnt:=length(closedList[0])-1 downto 0 do
                if (closedList[0, parentClosedListCnt]=closedList[4, closedListCnt]) and (closedList[1, parentClosedListCnt]=closedList[5, closedListCnt]) then break;
            closedListCnt:=parentClosedListCnt;

            { if (closedList[0, closedListCnt]=0) and (closedList[1, closedListCnt]=0) then break; }

        end;
        pathToControlledCharPtr:=length(getPath[0])-1;

    end;
end;
```

The steps I'm following are:

1. Add the starting square (or node) to the open list.
2. Repeat the following:

A) Look for the lowest F cost square on the open list. We refer to this as the current square.

B). Switch it to the closed list.

C) For each of the 8 squares adjacent to this current square …

- If it is not walkable or if it is on the closed list, ignore it. Otherwise do the following.
- If it isn’t on the open list, add it to the open list. Make the current square the parent of this square. Record the F, G, and H costs of the square.
- If it is on the open list already, check to see if this path to that square is better, using G cost as the measure. A lower G cost means that this is a better path. If so, change the parent of the square to the current square, and recalculate the G and F scores of the square. If you are keeping your open list sorted by F score, you may need to resort the list to account for the change.

D) Stop when you:

- Add the target square to the closed list, in which case the path has been found, or
- Fail to find the target square, and the open list is empty. In this case, there is no path.

3. Save the path. Working backwards from the target square, go from each square to its parent square until you reach the starting square. That is your path.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Learning to debug programs is an important step in becoming a developer.  The two most common methods are to add logging / debugging output to tell you what is happening, and to use an IDE to single step and set breakpoints.  Have you done either of those?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I have been debugging using the Free Pascal IDE for the past two days and cannot find a reason for why it is not working. I was hoping people who had successfully programmed A star could point out an error in the logic.I will keep debugging at some point. When I'm not frustrated.

Comment: At the moment the function stays stuck in the while loop. Which means the open list is never empty and the target node is never added to the closed list.

Comment: I think where it says "B). Switch it to the closed list" I need to remove it from the open list after adding it to the closed list. I think that's what is meant by "switch". Going to program this tomorrow as it's 00:54 right now.

Comment: So I found several things here and there in my code that were wrong. I fixed those and the getPath function returns values now and I can see the characters in the game walking along the returned path. However, it's a very wonky path lol. Which means the wrong nodes are being added to the closed list. Anyway I'll update my code in my original post.

Comment: It can help sometimes to work through very simple test data (like 3 nodes) on paper so you know what the behavior is supposed to be at each step, then compare that to what your code is doing.  If they don't match, figure out which one is wrong and why.

Comment: Dave S, yes this is exactly what I have been doing. I am taking a break for now until I have the stamina to keep debugging lol. Responsibilities in life getting in the way, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

This is the working code:

```
function getHeuristic(currentXY, targetXY: array of word): word;
begin
    getHeuristic:=abs(currentXY[0]-targetXY[0])+abs(currentXY[1]-targetXY[1]);
end;

function getPath(startingNodeXY, targetNodeXY: array of word; grid: wordArray3; out pathToControlledCharPtr: word; worldObjIndex: word): wordArray2;
var
    openList, closedList: array of array of word; { x/y/g/h/parent x/parent y, total }
    qXYGH: array[0..5] of word; { x/y/g/h/parent x/parent y }
    gridXCnt, gridYCnt: longInt;
    maxF, q, openListCnt, closedListCnt, parentClosedListCnt, getPathCnt, adjSquNewGScore: word;
    openListIndexCnt, closedListIndexCnt, qIndexCnt, successorIndexCnt: byte;
    getMaxF, successorOnClosedList, successorOnOpenList, pathFound: boolean;
begin

    { Add the starting square (or node) to the open list. }
    setLength(openList, 6, length(openList)+1);
    openList[0, 0]:=startingNodeXY[0];
    openList[1, 0]:=startingNodeXY[1];

    setLength(closedList, 6, 0);

    { Repeat the following: }
    { D) Stop when you: }
    { Fail to find the target square, and the open list is empty. In this case, there is no path. }
    pathFound:=false;
    { writeLn('h1'); }
    while length(openList[0])>0 do
    begin

        { A) Look for the lowest F cost square on the open list. We refer to this as the current square. }
        maxF:=0;
        q:=0;
        getMaxF:=true;
        for openListCnt:=0 to length(openList[0])-1 do
        begin
            //writeLn(formatVal('open list xy {} {}, cnt {}, list max index {}', [openList[0, openListCnt], openList[1, openListCnt], openListCnt, length(openList[0])-1]));
            { readLnPromptX; }
            if (getMaxF=true) or (maxF>openList[2, openListCnt]+openList[3, openListCnt]) then
            begin
                getMaxF:=false;
                maxF:=openList[2, openListCnt]+openList[3, openListCnt];
                q:=openListCnt;
            end;
        end;
        for qIndexCnt:=0 to length(qXYGH)-1 do
            qXYGH[qIndexCnt]:=openList[qIndexCnt, q];

        { B). Switch it to the closed list. }
        setLength(closedList, length(closedList), length(closedList[0])+1);
        for closedListIndexCnt:=0 to length(closedList)-1 do
            closedList[closedListIndexCnt, length(closedList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[closedListIndexCnt];

        { Remove current square from open list }
        if q<length(openList[0])-1 then
        begin
            for openListCnt:=q to length(openList[0])-2 do
            begin
                for openListIndexCnt:=0 to length(openList)-1 do
                    openList[openListIndexCnt, openListCnt]:=openList[openListIndexCnt, openListCnt+1];
            end;
        end;
        setLength(openList, length(openList), length(openList[0])-1);

        //writeLn(formatVal('q[x] {}, q[y] {}, startingNodeXY x {}, startingNodeXY y {}, targetNodeXY x {}, targetNodeXY y {}', [qXYGH[0], qXYGH[1], startingNodeXY[0], startingNodeXY[1], targetNodeXY[0], targetNodeXY[1]]));
        { readLnPromptX; }

        { D) Stop when you: }
        { Add the target square to the closed list, in which case the path has been found, or }
        if (qXYGH[0]=targetNodeXY[0]) and (qXYGH[1]=targetNodeXY[1]) then
        begin
            pathFound:=true;
            break;
        end;

        { C) For each of the 8 squares adjacent to this current square … }
        for gridXCnt:=qXYGH[0]-1 to qXYGH[0]+1 do
        begin
            for gridYCnt:=qXYGH[1]-1 to qXYGH[1]+1 do
            begin

                { Adjacent square cannot be the current square }
                if (gridXCnt<>qXYGH[0]) or (gridYCnt<>qXYGH[1]) then
                begin
                    //writeLn(formatVal('gridXCnt {} gridYCnt {} qXYGH[0] {} qXYGH[1] {}', [gridXCnt, gridYCnt, qXYGH[0], qXYGH[1]]));
                    { readLnPromptX; }

                    { Check if successor is on closed list }
                    successorOnClosedList:=false;
                    if length(closedList[0])>0 then
                    begin
                        for closedListCnt:=0 to length(closedList[0])-1 do
                        begin
                            if (closedList[0, closedListCnt]=gridXCnt) and (closedList[1, closedListCnt]=gridYCnt) then
                            begin
                                successorOnClosedList:=true;
                                break;
                            end;
                        end;
                    end;

                    { If it is not walkable or if it is on the closed list, ignore it. Otherwise do the following. }
                    if (gridXCnt>=0) and (gridXCnt<=length(grid[3])-1) and (gridYCnt>=0) and (gridYCnt<=length(grid[3, 0])-1) and (grid[3, gridXCnt, gridYCnt]=0) and (successorOnClosedList=false) then
                    begin

                        { If it isn’t on the open list, add it to the open list. Make the current square the parent of this square. Record the F, G, and H costs of the square. }
                        successorOnOpenList:=false;
                        if length(openList[0])>0 then
                        begin
                            for openListCnt:=0 to length(openList[0])-1 do
                            begin
                                if (openList[0, openListCnt]=gridXCnt) and (openList[1, openListCnt]=gridYCnt) then
                                begin
                                    successorOnOpenList:=true;
                                    break;
                                end;
                            end;
                        end;
                        if successorOnOpenList=false then
                        begin
                            setLength(openList, length(openList), length(openList[0])+1);
                            openList[0, length(openList[0])-1]:=gridXCnt;
                            openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]:=gridYCnt;
                            openList[4, length(openList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[0];
                            openList[5, length(openList[0])-1]:=qXYGH[1];
                            if (openList[0, length(openList[0])-1]=qXYGH[0]) or (openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]=qXYGH[1]) then
                            begin
                                openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]:=openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]+10;
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                                openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]:=openList[2, length(openList[0])-1]+14;
                            end;
                            openList[3, length(openList[0])-1]:=getHeuristic([openList[0, length(openList[0])-1], openList[1, length(openList[0])-1]], [targetNodeXY[0], targetNodeXY[1]]);
                        end
                        else
                        begin

                            { If it is on the open list already, check to see if this path to that square is better, using G cost as the measure (check to see if the G score for the adjacent square is lower if we use the current square to get there (adjacent square
                            new G score = current square G score + 10 (if adjacent squre is vertical or horizontal to current square) or +14 (if it is diagonal); if result is lower than adjacent square current G score then this path is better). A lower G cost means that
                            this is a better path. If so, change the parent of the square to the current square, and recalculate the G and F scores of the square. If you are keeping your open list sorted by F score, you may need to resort the list to account for the
                            change. }
                            adjSquNewGScore:=openList[2, openListCnt];
                            if (openList[0, openListCnt]=qXYGH[0]) or (openList[1, openListCnt]=qXYGH[1]) then
                            begin
                                adjSquNewGScore:=adjSquNewGScore+10;
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                                adjSquNewGScore:=adjSquNewGScore+14;
                            end;
                            if adjSquNewGScore<openList[2, openListCnt] then
                            begin
                                openList[4, openListCnt]:=qXYGH[0];
                                openList[5, openListCnt]:=qXYGH[1];
                                openList[2, openListCnt]:=adjSquNewGScore;
                            end;

                        end;

                    end;

                end;

            end;
        end;

    end;
    { writeLn('h2'); }
    { writeLn(pathFound); }
    { readLnHalt; }

    if pathFound=true then
    begin

        { Save the path. Working backwards from the target square, go from each square to its parent square until you reach the starting square. That is your path. }
        closedListCnt:=length(closedList[0])-1;
        setLength(getPath, 2, 0);

        { While starting node has not been added to path }
        while (length(getPath[0])=0) or (getPath[0, length(getPath[0])-1]<>startingNodeXY[0]) or (getPath[1, length(getPath[0])-1]<>startingNodeXY[1]) do
        begin

            { Add node from closed list to path }
            setLength(getPath, 2, length(getPath[0])+1);
            getPath[0, length(getPath[0])-1]:=closedList[0, closedListCnt];
            getPath[1, length(getPath[0])-1]:=closedList[1, closedListCnt];

            //writeLn(formatVal('path found {} {}, start {} {}, target {} {}', [getPath[0, length(getPath[0])-1], getPath[1, length(getPath[0])-1], startingNodeXY[0], startingNodeXY[1], targetNodeXY[0], targetNodeXY[1]]));
            { readLnPromptX; }

            { Find next node on closed list with coord matching parent coord of current closed list node }
            for parentClosedListCnt:=length(closedList[0])-1 downto 0 do
                if (closedList[0, parentClosedListCnt]=closedList[4, closedListCnt]) and (closedList[1, parentClosedListCnt]=closedList[5, closedListCnt]) then break;
            closedListCnt:=parentClosedListCnt;

            { if (closedList[0, closedListCnt]=0) and (closedList[1, closedListCnt]=0) then break; }

        end;
        pathToControlledCharPtr:=length(getPath[0])-1;

    end;
end;
```